# Regular expression for a string (image url checking)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need regular expression for a string is an image url.
I need three type of regular expression

1. start with slash(example : /p/230x230/9/Apple_iPad_2_16GB@@9ap4d206.png)
2. start with double slash(ex: //image)
3. start with http(ex: 'http://....')

Comment: if your idea of checking if a url points to an image by checking if the file extension is a known image extension that doesn't really serve the purpose.

Comment: No I am not checking extension i just need to check the starting character of string

Comment: how about `preg_match('/^(\/)|(http)/', 'http')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~(?>https?+:/|/)?(?>/[^/\s]++)+~';
```

explanations:

```
(?>           # open an atomic group *
    https?+   # http or https
    :/        #
   |          # OR
    /
)?            # close the atomic group and make it optional

(?>           # open an atomic group
    /
    [^/\s]++  # all characters except / or spaces one or more times (possessive *)
)+            # close the atomic group, one or more times
```

*(* more informations about [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).)*

Notice:

Since the pattern describe an url full of slashes, i use `~` as delimiter instead of the classical `/`. Thus the slashes don't need to be escaped in the pattern.

You can add anchors to this pattern to be sure that matches exactly your string from the begining to the end:

```
$pattern = '~^(?>https?+:/|/)?(?>/[^/\s]++)+$~';
```